# (Invalid) Fatal error in fresh skeleton Symfony 4 app

Tags: php, symfony

(Sorry I've discovered my question is invalid, you can see [the correct version of the question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450935/fatal-error-in-fresh-skeleton-symfony-4-app))

Right after creating a new app from symfony/skeleton, loading in the public dir in the browser yields internal server error 500.

The web server error log gets an entry such as this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: 
Class 'Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\void' not found in 
....hellow/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95\nStack trace:\n#0 
....hellow/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57): 
Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->populate(Array)\n#1 
....hellow/public/index.php(15): 
Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->load('.....')\n#2 {main}\n  
thrown in ....hellow/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 95
```

In index.php line 15 says:

```
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
```

In Dotenv.php on line 95 is the closing brace of the populate() method without return statment.

The versions of PHP and Symfony:

```
    php --version
    PHP 7.2.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 13:54:13) ( NTS )
    Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

    php ....hellow/bin/console --version
    Symfony 4.0.3 (kernel: src, env: dev, debug: true)
```

This is the content of ....hellow/.env file:

```
    $ cat ....hellow/.env
    # This file is a "template" of which env vars need to be defined for your application
    # Copy this file to .env file for development, create environment variables when deploying to production
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

    ###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
    APP_ENV=dev
    APP_SECRET=....
    #TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
    #TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
    ###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
```

[composer.json contents](https://pastebin.com/erTQF4Qu)

What is the proper way to make it work?

Comment: Do you have a hellow/.env file?

Comment: Yes, I have now added the contents of ....hellow/.env file at the bottom of my question

Comment: Sorry I discovered an error in my question, you can see [the correct question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450935/fatal-error-in-fresh-skeleton-symfony-4-app)

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy/paste your composer.json file here ?

In composer.json file, do you have `"symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",` into require-dev section ?

Comment: Yes, there is:
        "require-dev": {
            "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0"
        },
Will try to paste the whole composer.json file

Comment: Sorry I discovered an error in my question, you can see [the correct question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450935/fatal-error-in-fresh-skeleton-symfony-4-app)

Comment: i'ts work for me with your composer.json.

- `composer install`

- `php  -S localhost:8000 -t public`

- open `http://localhost:8000` in your browser

How do u run your local server ?

Comment: I didn't run the symfony's own server, but a normal Apache, it turned out the Apache was still using php7.0, which I didn't realize because php --version was giving me 7.2. Until I saw the result of phpinfo() in the browser which said 7.0 :)

Comment: You can also see [the correct version of the question and what I had to do to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450935/fatal-error-in-fresh-skeleton-symfony-4-app)