# Fatal error in fresh skeleton Symfony 4 app

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

(I have previously tried to ask the same question, but quoted the wrong error message; this is the correct version):

Right after creating a new app from symfony/skeleton, loading in the public dir in the browser yields internal server error 500.

The web server error log gets an entry such as this:

```
    [Thu Jan 25 19:26:35.881140 2018] [:error] [pid 26752] [client .....:64137]
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of
    Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of
    Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\void, none returned in
    ...../hellow/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95\n
    Stack trace:\n#0 ..../hellow/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57):
    Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->populate(Array)\n
    #1 ...../hellow/public/index.php(15): 
    Symfony\\Component\\Dotenv\\Dotenv->load('....')\n
    #2 {main}\n  thrown in ..../hellow/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php
    on line 95
```

In index.php line 15 says:

```
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
```

In Dotenv.php on line 95 is the closing brace of the populate() method without return statement.

The versions of PHP and Symfony:

```
    php --version
    PHP 7.2.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 13:54:13) ( NTS )
    Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

    php ....hellow/bin/console --version
    Symfony 4.0.3 (kernel: src, env: dev, debug: true)
```

This is the content of ....hellow/.env file:

```
    $ cat ....hellow/.env
    # This file is a "template" of which env vars need to be defined for your application
    # Copy this file to .env file for development, create environment variables when deploying to production
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

    ###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
    APP_ENV=dev
    APP_SECRET=....
    #TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
    #TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
    ###< symfony/framework-bundle ###
```

[composer.json contents](https://pastebin.com/erTQF4Qu)

To me it sounds like the populate() methods should return an object of class Symfony\Component\Dotenv\void, but it sounds very strange to have such an omission in the skeleton?

What is the proper way to make it work?

Comment: Verify that your web server is actually using php 7.2 and not some earlier version.  You can use something like <? phpinfo();  Dotenv::populate() returns void so it is not an omission.

Comment: Many thanks, I did just that and it worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

It turned out apache2 was still using the old php 7.0, instead of the recently installed php7.2.

php --version was showing 7.2, which made me confident I'm running 7.2, until I checked the result of phpinfo() in the browser.

I had to do:

```
    apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.2
    a2dismod php7.0
    a2enmod php7.2
    service apache2 restart
```

And then the skeleton app worked correctly!